# AngularJS directive with $http creates memory leak - .resolve doesn't seem to work?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, memory-leaks

I seem to have a problem and I don't think I can see the solution, perhaps someone can help... I have an AngularJS directive that makes a `$http` request that returns HTML and I inject it into my view when there is content - I know this isn't great and the returning of HTML should be replaced with JSON and the use of templates but I have no control over the content that is returned from the $http request. The directive takes some arguments/attributes to get the correct content and all seems to work. The direct is usually in 7 places in my view, one in my navigation which I add to my index using ng-include, three times in my footer which I add to my index.html using `ng-include` and then the directive appears within the `ng-view` tag I have, the tag can appear from 0 to three times per view. This is the directive in my HTML

```
<div data-cms-inject data-page-name="homePageContent" data-slot-name="slot1"></div>
```

Here is the JS...

```
.directive('cmsInject', ['$rootScope', '$q', '$http', function ($rootScope, $q, $http) {
        'use strict';
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

                var canceller = $q.defer(),
                    cmsPromise = $http({
                    url : 'url/to/feed',
                    timeout: canceller.promise,
                    method: 'POST',
                    data: [{
                    pageName: attrs.pageName,
                    slotName: attrs.slotName
                    }]
                });

                cmsPromise.success(function(data) {

                    var resp = data[0];

                    if(resp.replace(/\s{1,}/,'').replace(/\r?\n|\r/g,'') !== 'null') {
                        element.html(resp);
                    }
                    console.log('new request success');
                    $rootScope.$broadcast('cmsLoaded');
                }).error(function(data) {
                    console.log('new request error', data);

                }) ;

                $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function () {
                    console.log('$locationChangeStart');
                    canceller.resolve('locationChange');
                });

            }
        };
    }])
```

Now this seems to work fine, but when I quickly navigate between views in my app I notice the application seems to slow, then crashes the browser, thus we have a memory leak. At first I thought it was due to the pending $http calls but when I tried to resolve these using the timeout and the '$locationChangeStart' event the problem remained. I then tried to write to the console to see what happens... this is the output I have...

This is when I load the app, we have 7 instances of the directive, 3 are within the ng-view, 4 outside in ng-includes

```
7 new request success
```

I then switch to a new view with no directives

```
7 $locationChangeStart
```

I then navigate back to the original view

```
7 $locationChangeStart
3 new request success
```

Once more I switch to a new view with no directives

```
10 $locationChangeStart
```

I navigate back to the original view

```
10 $locationChangeStart
3 new request success
```

Once more I switch to a new view with no directives

```
13 $locationChangeStart
```

and finally back to the original view

```
13 $locationChangeStart
3  new request success
```

Something is strange here as the number of times the $locationChangeStart event is being called increases, more times than the directive appears within the page, ng-include + ng-view can anyone see what I am doing wrong here, some drectives are being left in the memory/DOM I guess?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The increasing number of event handlers can be explained:

```
$rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart'
```

You attach an event handler to `$rootScope` and that, of course, doesn't disappear when the directive's lifecycle ends. The event handler should be attached to `scope` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your directive creates circular references between DOM and js objects. Try to avoid binding events to rootScope and using services like $http inside directive link function. Better solution is place this logic in module run function.

Something like that:

```
.run(['$rootScope', 'myService',  function($rootScope, myService){

    $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function () {
       myService.doSomethng().then(function(data){
            var resp = data[0];
            if(resp.replace(/\s{1,}/,'').replace(/\r?\n|\r/g,'') !== 'null') {
               $rootScope.$broadcast('cmsLoaded', data);
            }
       });
    });

}])
.directive('cmsInject', ['$rootScope', '$q', '$http', function ($rootScope, $q, $http) {
        'use strict';
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
               scope.$on('cmsLoaded', function(e, args) {
                    element.html(args);                    
               })
            }
        }
     }])
```

Answer (score 1):

Move your http calls to some service and use that service in your directive. Listen for '$destory' event of directive and do some clean up if you can.

Comment: Can you expland on what I need to do when listening for the  '$destory' event of directive - thanks

Comment: You can remove event handlers which are attached using jQuery if exist in your code. You can clear timeouts. You can remove watches if you are using in your code.

Comment: I have fixed it by removing all references to the $rootScope, but that's for the advice on $destroy!